# Regex return something else when matching

Tags: regex

I have the input:
`John went in Columbia in vacation.`

I need a regex to return `John` if `Columbia` is in the input or
                          empty string if other state rather than `Columbia` is in the input

Can this be done?

Comment: `if (thing is present) return this else return that`. so... yes?

Comment: Sure, they have a special syntax for that in regex called `(?returnonlyifininputandisstate:John,Columbia)`.

Comment: I need this done through a regex, no code]

Comment: can anyone help me with a sample of regex?

Comment: Something like `^\w+(?=.*\bColumbia\b)`? Far away from failsafe, but at least an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(John)(?=.*?\bColumbia\b)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA6mG4/1)

Comment: so what if I change Columbia to another state? I want an empty string

Comment: `(John)(?=.*?Columbia)|`

Comment: `(John).*?(?:(?:\bColumbia\b)|(?:\bParis\b)|(?:\bLondon\b))`